# Negation of the following statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

given the statement. there exists $U \in \tau$ : $x\in U$ and $U \subset A$

Why is the negation of the above statement the following:

For each $U \in \tau$, $x \notin U$ or $U$ is not a subset of $A$?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The negation of

> There exists $U \in \tau$: $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$

of course is:

> There does not exist $U \in \tau$: $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$.

Now if there exists no object for which the condition holds, then for each object the condition does not hold. Thus the above is equivalent to:

> For each $U\in\tau$, it is not the case that both $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$.

But if it is not true that $P$ *and* $Q$ hold, it means at least one of them does not hold, that is, $P$ does not hold *or* $Q$ does not hold. Thus the statement is further equivalent to

> For each $U\in\tau$, not $x\in U$, or not $U\subset A$.

And now we're there: not $x\in U$ is commonly written $x\notin U$, and not $U\subset A$ means $U$ is not a subset of $A$. Thus:

> For each $U\in\tau$, $x\notin U$ or $U$ is not a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the negation of a quantifier statement $\forall U \in \tau: P(U)$ is the statement $\exists U \in \tau: \neg P(U)$. Furthermore, if $P(U)$ is of the form $Q(U) \wedge R(U)$, then the negation of $P(U)$ is $\neg Q(U) \vee \neg R(U)$.

In your case, $Q(U)$ is $x \in U$ and $R(U)$ is $U \subset A$.